# How to safely XSS encode untrusted data coming from PHP through AJAX injected into the DOM via javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, xss

I felt pretty confident with XSS prevention with an older setup we had on our site ... we were using OWASP's XSS mitigation functions for stroking out user supplied data from a database (we inject values into DB directly via prepared statements, no encoding takes place till output time) and printing it via (simplified for readability):

### show.php

```
print "<li>";
print "<a href='page?id=".xssafe($row->TRUSTED_VALUE)."'>".xssafe($row->UNTRUSTED_VALUE)."</a>";
print "</li>";
```

For numerous reasons, scalability, pagination, flexibility, we're switching to an AJAX oriented scheme.  Instead of printing out these LI blocks directly, we AJAX them in immediately on page load (technically $(document).ready()) and let the client via javascript & jQuery handle everything. I'm concerned about this approach as I've read a ton on the subject and am still not confident in how to maintain XSS security.

Our new setup is this:

### retrieve.php (I originally still had the xssafe() wrappers, but read that I should just use json_encode())

```
$data['TRUSTED_VALUE'] = $row->TRUSTED_VALUE; // 123
$data['UNTRUSTED_VALUE'] = $row->UNTRUSTED_VALUE; // who knows?
header('Content-Type: application/json');
print json_encode($data);
```

### show.php

```
<script src="show.js"></script>
```

### show.js

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'retrive.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {page: pageNum},
        success: loadLI
}); 

function loadLI() {
        data = response.data;
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        var anchor = document.createElement('a');
        anchor.setAttribute('href', 'page?id='+encodeURIComponent(data.TRUSTED_VALUE));
        anchor.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.UNTRUSTED_VALUE));
        li.appendChild(anchor);

}
```

Should I keep the xssafe() wrapper functions in our retrieve.php script, then json_encode, then inject those values via Javascript?  Or is our new setup safe?  Or is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: You still need to encode the untrusted values (e.g. htmlencode). Json encode takes no care of XSS.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois OK, thanks.  Do we html encode things from the PHP side prior to json_encoding or somehow html encode using javascript once we have ajax'd data over?  If the latter, are there functions in JS that can safely encode data to inject into HTML.  I can't seem to find built in functions, the closest I've seen is Reform.js or jqencode, but neither seem to be extremely popular which worries me.  Also, I thought I've read that using javascript to document.createTextNode() is a safe way to inject untrusted data

Comment: You htmlencode on the serverside the untrusted data (e.g. user input data from the database), if you would htmlencode the finished data/html, you'd also make your own HTML code useless.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Thank you, so if I understand correctly, we should be okay if I modify the new retrieve.php script to encode values via xssafe() first (like we used to do), then json_encode prior to sending data via AJAX.  Once javascript decodes the json data, it is already properly html encoded, so we shouldn't run into any problems injecting data into the DOM?

Comment: Yes. You just need to make sure that anything that came from the user gets htmlencoded, so that no XSS can oncurr. E.g. if you send `<script>alert('Hi');</script>` to the database and then print it on your page you should see this as a text. To do that you html encode the user input. Your own HTML should not be html encoded or it won't be interpreted as HTML. I don't really know if you will just send the user input with JSON to the frontend and make the HTML code there or still make the HTML code on the server and just push the finished HTML code back (that's what I'd do).

Comment: Depending on the use-case one or the other is better.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing appears safe.

`createTextNode` creates a text node on the page - JavaScript will handle the encoding internally for you.

`setAttribute` will set an attribute on the page - the same applies here, the parameter is taken as a strongly typed value and it shouldn't be possible to escape it using malicious code.

> Should I keep the xssafe() wrapper functions in our retrieve.php
>   script, then json_encode

So, no.